# Remove white space using clearfix:after

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble removing the whitespace generated by clearing the float (whitespace after the tabs). Do you guys know how to solve this problem?

Here is the code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acjrdesigner/ob0ja16n/)):

```
/* Clearfix */
    .clearfix:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      content: " ";
      height: 0;
      font-size: 0;
      clear: both;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: The gap is a result of the margin from the `p` element within the tab content... Here is an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ce9yege/) with the `margin-top` removed:  `.tab-content p { margin-top: 0; }`.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoshCrozier !

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the clearfix, it's the default padding on the `p` element. Typically we zero these out at the beginning of the style sheet.

```
p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```